# regression with given upper and lower bounds for the target value

Tags: regression, forecasting, bounds

I am using several regressors like xgboost, gradient boosting, random forest or decision tree to predict a continuous target value. 
I have some complementary information like I know my prediction (target value) based on all features that I have should be in a given range.

Is there any way to more effectively take into consideration these bounds as a feature to any of these algorithms instead of verifying the range on already predicted values and only doing some post-processing.

Note that by just simply putting the lower and upper bound for my target value, not necessarily these algorithms will learn to effectively compute the prediction in the given range. I am looking for more effective way to take into consideration these bounds as a given data.

Thanks

Comment: One possibility is to return a very large value - and therefore a very large error - if the function yields a value outside the bounds. This is a somewhat crude "brick wall" technique that is usually easy to implement and quick to test, and as a practical matter can sometimes yield useful results. If the initial optimization starting parameters are outside the bounds, the optimizing algorithm will fail as it cannot properly start, and this is a consideration when using this technique.

Comment: It seems an interesting point. I think most of algorithms have some scaling process to avoid that scale of one feature has an extreme effect, I will check it. Thanks